# Convert nvarchar to datetime

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've got difficulty to convert that nvarchar to datetime.
Here is the format 'ddmmyy'

```
declare @mydate nvarchar(50) = '211077' 

select convert(datetime,@mydate,103)
```

Comment: 211077 is 21101977 or 21101877 or 21101277??

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DECLARE @mydate NVARCHAR(50) = '211077' 

SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, '19' + SUBSTRING(@mydate, 5, 2) + SUBSTRING(@mydate,3, 2) + LEFT(@mydate, 2), 103)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for those who get the same problem :

```
declare @mydate nvarchar(50) = '211077'
select @mydate, convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(@mydate,5,0,'.'),3,0,'.'), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you can try this

```
DECLARE @mydate NVARCHAR(50) = '211077' 
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@mydate, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@mydate, 3, 2) +  '-19' + RIGHT(@mydate, 2), 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @mydate nvarchar(50) = '21-10-1977' 

select convert(datetime,@mydate,103)
```

Comment: I can't try this. All the values int he columns are made in this format 'ddmmyy'

Comment: @Chris are the dates greater than 2000? and how are they stored?

Comment: No some date are like this 290799 for 29/07/1999